# Maximum Variance of a Distribution

Tags: probability, variance

Let the random variable $X$ have the distribution $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\mathbb{P}(X=2)$, $\mathbb{P}(X=1)=1-2p$ for $0\leq p \leq 1/2$. For what $p$ is the $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ maximum ?

Comment: Please show your work and where you faced problems.

Comment: I am not able to understand what would be the condition for Maximum Variance? So  I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: @AkashJain, please use MathJax for math formulas.

Comment: Did you write down the expression for $Var(X)$? What relationship did you see between $Var(X)$ and $p$? Also what did you find out about $P(X=0)=P(X=2)=?$

Comment: Because once you find out the probabilities of $X=0$ and $X=2$ you just need to write down the variance expression, which I think will be a simple polynomial in $p$ and differentiate.

Comment: @Hayk, Sure, will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: @Vizag I did write down the equation for Var(X). But since, I was getting two unknowns, I didn't know how to proceed further.

Comment: You won't get two unknowns. That's because you didn't calculate $P(X=0)$ and $P(X=2)$. They will come out in terms of $p$. Assuming $0,1,2$ are the only values that $X$ takes, what will the sum of these probabilities be?

Comment: @Vizag, The sum of probabilities will be 1. And solving that I get the value of P(X=0) as p. After that how do I proceed further.

Comment: $Var(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$

Comment: I do know that formula, but how do I find the Expectation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of expectation, $E(X) = 0*P(X=0)+1P(X=1)+2P(X=2)$. Note that $P(X=0) + P(X=2) = 1-P(X=1)=2p$. Thus, $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=p$ and $E(X) = 0*p + 1*(1-2p) + 2p = 1$. Furthermore, $E(X^2) = 1*(1-2p) + 4*p=1+2p$. The variance, $V(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$ is maximal for $p=1/2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation..